# Generic signature for Enum types

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have several `Enum` types defined across my project, used for object-specific state identifiers:

```
  public enum ObjectAState
  {
    ObjectAAvailable,
    ObjectADeleteRequested,
    ObjectADeleted
  }
  public enum ObjectBState
  {
    ObjectBCreationRequested,
    ObjectBCreationFailed,
    ObjectBDeleteRequested,
    ObjectBDeleted
  }
```

Anyone using ObjectA can only refer to ObjectA enums, and the same is true of all the other objects - their enums are isolated, and this makes them easier to understand since states which are not applicable to an object are not shown (this is why I don't just put all the states for all objects in a single `enum`).

For a given state, there are zero, one or many other states (within the same `enum`) which can follow; by definition, there are also certain states which cannot follow. In `ObjectA`, for example, the state can transition from `ObjectAAvailable` to `ObjectADeleteRequested`, and from `ObjectADeleteRequested` to `ObjectADeleted`, but not directly from `ObjectAAvailable` to `ObjectADeleted`. In each object there is a tedious and repetitive bit of code to enforce valid state transitions, which I want to replace with a single method.

As a test, I did this:

```
Dictionary<ObjectAState, List<ObjectAState>> Changes = new Dictionary<ObjectAState, List<ObjectAState>>();
```

This is a `Dictionary` accessed via `ObjectAState` as a key, holding a `List` of other `ObjectAState` values which indicate valid transitions populated thus:

```
Changes.Add(ObjectAState.ObjectAAvailable, new List<ObjectAState> { ObjectAState.ObjectADeleteRequested });
Changes.Add(ObjectAState.ObjectAADeleteRequested, new List<ObjectAState> { ObjectAState.ObjectADeleted });
Changes.Add(ObjectAState.ObjectADeleted, null);
```

And I have a method which simply looks like this:

```
public bool StateTransitionIsValid(ObjectAState currentState, ObjectAState targetState)
{
  return Changes[currentState].Contains(targetState);
}
```

This works perfectly - users of ObjectA simply pass in the `enum` of the current and target states of the object and get a simple true or false for whether the transition is valid. So, how to make this generic so that the same method can handle enums from other objects?

I tried this:

```
Dictionary<Enum, List<Enum>> Changes = new Dictionary<Enum, List<Enum>>();
```

It compiles without error - but the code which adds entries to the Dictionary fails:

```
Changes.Add(ObjectAState.ObjectAAvailable, new List<ObjectAState> { ObjectAState.ObjectADeleteRequested });

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Enum,System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Enum>>.Add(System.Enum, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Enum>)' has some invalid arguments
Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.ObjectAState>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Enum>'
```

I've had a hunt around and can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong. Anyone got any ideas why my 'generic' version doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you are trying to use a non generic object although the definition was generic. try this.

```
Changes.Add(ObjectAState.ObjectAAvailable, new List<Enum> { ObjectAState.ObjectADeleteRequested });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - and now I see it, it's obvious. Doh!

Answer (score 3):

Your method or class must be generically defined, so that you have an actual generic type to work with.

The difficulty is that there is no way to fully enforce that the generic type is an Enum at compile time. This is probably the closest you'll come:

```
public class MyTestClass<T>
    where T : struct, IConvertible // Try to get as much of a static check as we can.
{
    // The .NET framework doesn't provide a compile-checked
    // way to ensure that a type is an enum, so we have to check when the type
    // is statically invoked.
    static EnumUtil()
    {
        // Throw Exception on static initialization if the given type isn't an enum.
        if(!typeof (T).IsEnum) 
            throw new Exception(typeof(T).FullName + " is not an enum type.");
    }

    Dictionary<T, List<T>> Changes = new Dictionary<T, List<T>>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can pin it down slightly further: `where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable`

Comment: It looks like this answer is about trying to ensure that the generic type is an Enum? If so, that wasn't really my question - I wasn't trying to enforce the Enum type, only get the generic definition working *with* an Enum. Thanks anyway, this may come in useful elsewhere.